# Dynamically disable closing bootstrap modal when esc or outside is pressed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal inside which I have a form. Submitting this form takes a couple of seconds during which if a user clicks on the outside or presses `esc`, modal is closed. I want to disable this when submitting:

```
$("#submit-btn").on("click", function(){
    // disable esc and outside

    submit()
})
```

But I want to enable the user to press `esc` to close the window if he has not submitted yet. That's why I cannot use this on my modal-opening button:

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

I tried this:

```
$("#submit-btn").on("click", function(){
    $.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
    $.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.keyboard = false;

    submit()
})
```

Did not help.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#submit-btn").on("click", function(){
  $('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = false;
  $('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
  submit();
});
```

Comment: I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov  What version of bootstrap are you using? And just to confirm, you put your `modal` div's id in place of `#myModal`?

Comment: I am using bootstrap v3.2! and yes! I did this: `$('#split-location-modal')` to be exact

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Please try with `$('#myModal').data('bs.modal')` once. I have updated the code in my answer.

Comment: okay, so, setting `backdrop` to `static` helped! It disabled clicking on the outside! However, for some reason, `keyboard=false` did not help! still closes on `esc`. Any ideas?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov You're right. Actually the keyboard disable does not work for the first time as the modal is open. If you open the modal again, then you can see the keyboard does not work. Doesn't help in your case though. I'll try to find a workaround and update my answer, if I get something.

Comment: in bootstrap 4 it is `$('#myModal').data('bs.modal')._config.keyboard` and `$('#myModal').data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop`

Comment: @wdetac Thanks for the info. I'll check and update my answer to include your updated version.